# Value_counts - Pandas - Dataframe - Quantidade zero

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um dataframe com uma coluna de horas e a outra o tipo de `relampago`.Eu estou fazendo um `value_counts` para contar a quantidade de `relampagos` em cada hora o dia. O `value_conts` está dando certo, porém tem algumas horas do dia que não tem `relampagos`, mas ai não está aparecendo na série. Por exemplo eu queria que depois q eu dei um `value_counts`, eu queria que aparecesse uma série com as 24 horas e cada hora a quantidade de `relampagos`, e isso aparece, porém as horas que não teve `relampagos`, ele pula. Mas eu queria q aparecesse todas as horas, e mesmo as que não tivesse `relampago`, aparecesse o zero sabe? Pois irei precisar disso,  mas não estou conseguindo. Já tentei usar `np.arange`, `sort_index(level=)`, `.fillna(0)`. Mas não está dando certo. Minha célula está assim:

```
quantidade_IC = IC["hor"].value_counts(ascending=True)
quantidade_IC.sort_index()
display(quantidade_IC.sort_index())
```

Ai o resultado (as horas 11 e 12 não aparecem com o zero na frente :/)

```
0       510
1       772
2       275
3        50
4        12
5        16
6        41
7       319
8       201
9        25
10       10
13       29
14      138
15      799
16     3619
17     9622
18    10935
19    13851
20    10928
21     6227
22     1500
23      594
```

Comment: faz um dicionário com todas horas do dia como chave e com valor 0 para cada uma. Depois faz um update nela com o retorno do q vc tem de numeração dos raios em determinada hora. depois é so printar esta lista.

Comment: pode disponibilizar um dataset de exemplo?

Comment: meu dataframe tem 72603 rows × 2 columns

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no comentário acima:

### Importando bibliotecas

```
import pandas as pd
import random
```

### Variáveis auxiliares

```
tamanho = 1000
horas = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23] # sem 11 e 12
```

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"hora": [random.choice(horas) for _ in range(tamanho)], "relampago": [int(random.random()*10) for _ in range(tamanho)]})
```

### Criando dicionário auxiliar

```
d = dict(zip(range(24), [0]*24))

print(d)

{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0}
```

### Atualizando dicionário auxiliar

```
d.update(df.groupby("hora")["hora"].count().to_dict())

print(d)

{0: 54, 1: 43, 2: 48, 3: 52, 4: 52, 5: 41, 6: 50, 7: 49, 8: 39, 9: 47, 10: 45, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 53, 14: 38, 15: 46, 16: 52, 17: 45, 18: 42, 19: 35, 20: 48, 21: 52, 22: 32, 23: 37}
```

### Transformando dicionário em dataframe

```
c = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=["qtd"])

print(c)

    qtd
0    54
1    43
2    48
3    52
4    52
5    41
6    50
7    49
8    39
9    47
10   45
11    0
12    0
13   53
14   38
15   46
16   52
17   45
18   42
19   35
20   48
21   52
22   32
23   37
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!!! Ajudou bastante!